# Wampserver Showing Only Red Icon

Tags: apache, dll, wampserver

It been four days since my wampserver suddenly stopped working "I mean non of its services is starting" and its just shows red icon and refuses to do any other thing.

[image]

I have no skype installed on my pc or any such thing that could occupy my port 80
After running the test port 80 on Apache it got this

[image]

and when i run `httpd.exe -e debug` on the Apache bin directory i got the follow error message
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, what version of WAMPServer are you using please

Comment: Also have you installed any ADDON's for Apache from the original install

Comment: Hi, @RiggsFolly am no longer with the system on which am experiencing the problem but i beleive the version is 3.2 and i've never had tp install any Apache addons